# Ionic / Capacitor - PushNotiifcations - Android - “notification” + “data” message

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I am using PushNotifications Capacitor plugin and FCM to send the notifications, everything works fine until I want to send a Push Notification with both `notification` and `data` fields on Android.

What I want to do is to send a custom data with the notification and consume the notification on app resume. I am using `PushNotifications.getDeliveredNotifications()` method to get the notifications on resume, on iOS I get all the notifications with proper `data`, but on Android `data` property is replaced with the object below:

```
{
  body: "My Body",
  data: {
    android.appInfo: "ApplicationInfo{809371c app}",
    android.bigText: "My Body",
    android.progress: 0,
    android.progressIndeterminate: false,
    android.progressMax: 0,
    android.reduced.images: true,
    android.showChronometer: false,
    android.showWhen: true,
    android.template: "android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle",
    android.text: "My Body",
    android.title: "My Title",
    gameDndOn: false,
    specialType: "",
    topFullscreen: false,
    groupSummary: false,
    id: 0,
    title: "My Title"
  }
}
```

I see in the FCM docs for Android apps that if both notification and data fields are present and the app is in the background the notification lands in the system tray and data in extras of the intent.

I am getting proper data when I tap on the notification, but in my case I want to get that on resume, without tapping on the notification.

Is there any way to get to that data in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the message in this format

```
{
"message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Note : `notification` structure is critical for receiving a notification. You need to have `title` and `body`. This gets displayed in the notification drawer.

`data` can be customized as per your requirement. This will have the data that you need inside your app.

Suggestion, keep your payload small. Send data which is absolutely necessary and also safe to send over FCM.

Look at this part of the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload)

For handling push notifications in capacitor, you should use the listeners. Here is the [official docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications#method-addListener-2) way of doing it.

Comment: This is not the issue, I use exactly the format you provided. I am also handling the notifications using proper listeners. I am receiving the notification properly. I do have access to `data` when the app is the foreground and when I tap on the notification.

I do not have access to `data` property when I receive the notification in the background and then resume the app (but not by tapping on the notification). Is there a way to get the notifications `data` in that case?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with how the messages are [handled on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)

_"Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity."_